# Memory leak in C++ program JNI environment

Tags: c++

I have c++ program which in turn calls JAVA function ( which calls some API to get the result). The API which java is calling creating lot of memory to server request ( 1 GB memory for every 1000000 requests).

Can we free the memory from c/c++ program? or instruct the JVM to free the memory? It would be great help if you can help on this.

Thanks in advance...

Thanks 
Sambasiva.

Comment: I hear that most of memory leaks when working with JNI is on the C++/JNI boundary. Check that you understand well how is all the memory owned and managed.

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe you can write a function in the java code that makes the free and call it from c++. Did you tried this?

Comment: We are using third party JAR file to achieve  the functionality. cleaning that jar has not provided any option to free memory which is allocated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. we have the leak with your suggestion by clearing all the resources / destroying the object once in a while ( every 100000 messages).

Answer (score 0):

Make explicit method that free all your resources in your C++ program

and try below code in your java class.

```
/******************************************************************************/
/*  File        : NativeCodeHandle.java                                       */
/*  Description : Blog-posting or Educational purpose                         */
/*  Written     : 2010.07.11                                                  */
/*  Version     : -_+                                                         */
/*  Author      : a.k.a LaZy Developer                                        */
/*  Contacts    : chriskr7@gmail.com                                          */
/******************************************************************************/

class someNativeClass{
  public native void allocateSomeMemory();
  public native void freeSomeMemory();
  static
  {
    System.loadLibrary("someSoDLLFile");
  }
}

public class NativeCodeHandle {

  boolean isCleaned = false;

  someNativeClass nativeObject = new someNativeClass();

  public synchronized void allocate(){
    nativeObject.allocateSomeMemory();
  }

  public synchronized void cleanup(){
    if(isCleaned) return;
    // free native code - maybe JNI free() wrapper method    
    nativeObject.freeSomeMemory();
    // maybe close DB connection
  }

  public void finalize(){
    cleanup();
    try {
      super.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
  }
 /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    NativeCodeHandle test = new NativeCodeHandle();
    test.allocate();
    // Explicit clean up!!! :P
    test.cleanup();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i am calling JAVA function in c++ program and all the members allocated in c and java process have been cleaned ( Variables and return values returned by java) but the problem is we are invoking third utility to do the job the memory eaten by the third party API. When we take the trace ( dump) we observed that third party library/ utility not freed the memory allocated. can we do something in java /c++ to take back memory which is taken by JVM?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do unless you can modify your third party java class .

Also there are many risk if you call the third party java class more than once

if you force to free the resource from c++.